# C++ ampersand before class name in bind function

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I was studying boost library and stuck at this line:

```
boost::bind(&Chat_Client::handle_connection, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error);
```

Can someone explain to me, what this ampersand `&Chat_Client::handle_connection` means? I haven't seen such syntax before. `handle_connection` function isn't `static`. Documentation says

> bind(&X::f, args) is equivalent to bind(mem_fn(&X::f), args)

It's not getting clearer. SOS.

Comment: you know the adress-of operator for "normal" variables, right?

Comment: Pointer-to-member.

Comment: @tobi300, sure. Is it same?

Comment: why does it have to be static? member functions are still functions, you can take their address  the same way, and `bind` can work with them, it just needs one extra argument (`this`)

Comment: "why does it have to be static?" -  well, I assumed it because of the resolution operator; Since this is not a instance of a class and we addressing to member function...Does it make sense ?

Comment: @that_Tony it does make some sense, you won't be able to call this function via pointer if you don't have the object, but notice that you do pass `this` to `bind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind takes a function pointer or functor.

`handle_connection` is a function. Specifically, it is a member function of `Chat_Client`. A function, begins somewhere in the executable portion in memory. To call a function, you start executing code at that address. When binding a function to a `boost::function` variable, the thing that is being remembered is the function pointer (where should I go when I try to call this `boost::function`?).

`handle_connection` is implemented in `Chat_Client`. In memory, the function will be laid out once and simply called with different `this` pointers to the current instance. This is why:

1. You still specify the function using `&Chat_Client::handle_connection`
2. You need to pass `this` as the first bound argument, even though `Chat_Client*` is not part of the `handle_connection` signature.

Comment: `bind` takes more than pointers.  It also works with functors.

Comment: I see, so this is an ordinary function pointer. I didn't recognize it.

Comment: @that_Tony It is not an ordinary function pointer.  `&Chat_Client::handle_connection` is a pointer to a member function which is a special beast.

Comment: @EyasSH, "2. You need to pass this as the first bound argument, even though Chat_Client* is not part of the handle_connection signature." - is it because we have to tell "Who is an actual caller of the function?"?

Comment: @that_Tony: Kind of. Not the "caller" of the function, but what the instance the function being called on is.